# DAX TopN Behavior

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Just wanted to confirm my understanding (or lack thereof) around these two formulas - in an orders table where each row is an order:

`TOPN(10,ALL(Orders),[Total Sales])` - looks at the individual Sales amount for each row and returns the whole table with just the top 10 records sorted by the Sales field; using the measure `Total Sales`(defined as Sum of Sales) in this context doesn't really have an effect as the aggregation is at a single row level which just keeps it the same.

`TOPN(10,ALL(Orders[Customer Name]),[Total Sales])` - this actually groups by the customer name, calculates the total sales, and returns the top 10 customer names based on that metric; it's more or less equivalent to this SQL:

```
select customer_name, sum(sales) as Total_Sales from orders
 group by customer_name
 order by Total_Sales desc
 limit 10
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Do you have any question?

Comment: Not at the moment, thanks for confirming!

Comment: Something came to mind - it's not immediately obvious to someone new in DAX, but this expression is also doing a `group by` on customer name behind the scenes, right? 

`FILTER(VALUES(Orders[Customer Name]),[Total Sales])`

Comment: yes, correct again.